# Что не так с моим слайдером?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Немного освоившись в JS'e и jQuery, попробовал написать свой слайдер.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gallery-dot:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");
    $(window).on("resize load",function(){
        if ($(window).width() <= 767){
            $(".gallery-current-image").css("object-fit","contain");
        } else {
            $(".gallery-current-image").css("object-fit","cover");
        }
    })

    var images = [];
    var i = 0;
    for (var image of $(".gallery-item-image")){
        images.push($(image).attr("src"));
    }

    setInterval(function(){return i++}, 2000);

    setInterval(function(){
        if (i == images.length){
            i = 0;
            var prev_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[images.length-1];
        } else {
            var prev_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[i-1];
        }
        var current_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[i];
        
        $(".gallery-current-image").attr("src",images[i]);
        $(current_dot).css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");
        $(prev_dot).css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
    }, 2000);

    $(".gallery-dot").on("click",function(){
        let clicked_dot_index = $(this).index();
        let old_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[i];
        let new_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[clicked_dot_index];

        $(old_dot).css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
        $(new_dot).css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");
        $(".gallery-current-image").attr("src",images[clicked_dot_index]);
        i = clicked_dot_index;
    });
});
```

```css
.gallery-all-images,.low-res{
    display: none;
}

.gallery-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.gallery-img-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-current-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: black;
}

.gallery-dots{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.65);
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
}

.gallery-dot{
    width: 1rem;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #a6a6a6;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0.70rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/static/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="gallery-wrapper">
                        <div class="gallery-img-wrapper">
                        <img src="https://belgium-guide.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/foto-hallerbosa-17.jpg" alt="" class="gallery-current-image">
                            <div class="gallery-dots">
                                <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
                                <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
                                <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
                                <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-all-images">
                            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://belgium-guide.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/foto-hallerbosa-17.jpg" alt="">
                            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://tumentoday.ru/media/gallery_images/bialowiezaforestctomaszwilk0.jpg" alt="">
                            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/25978/ee1780c5-7223-4d25-8ed3-6c16c2c2a1fa/orig" alt="">
                            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/25978/3b8dd671-b906-4216-a8f7-60b3ffdb5a16/orig" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/static/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Я хочу чтобы после клика на одну из точек, слайдер стоял на месте еще 2 секунды. Сейчас же, если подождать секунду-полторы, то таймер продолжит идти в своим чередом. Я пытался сбросить таймер и поставить по новой,но, слайдер почему-то ускорялся в 2 раза после каждого сброса интервала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - завести флаг, который пропускает одно переключение:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gallery-dot:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");
  $(window).on("resize load", function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
      $(".gallery-current-image").css("object-fit", "contain");
    } else {
      $(".gallery-current-image").css("object-fit", "cover");
    }
  })

  var images = [];
  var i = 0;
  var skipOneChange;
  
  for (var image of $(".gallery-item-image")) {
    images.push($(image).attr("src"));
  }

  setInterval(function() {
  
    if (skipOneChange) {      
      skipOneChange = false;
      return;
    }
  
    i++

    if (i == images.length) {
      i = 0;
      var prev_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[images.length - 1];
    } else {
      var prev_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[i - 1];
    }
    var current_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[i];

    $(".gallery-current-image").attr("src", images[i]);
    $(current_dot).css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");
    $(prev_dot).css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
    
  }, 2000);

  $(".gallery-dot").on("click", function() {
    let clicked_dot_index = $(this).index();
    let old_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[i];
    let new_dot = $(".gallery-dot")[clicked_dot_index];

    $(old_dot).css("background-color", "#a6a6a6");
    $(new_dot).css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");
    $(".gallery-current-image").attr("src", images[clicked_dot_index]);
    i = clicked_dot_index;
    
    skipOneChange = true; ///
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery-all-images,
.low-res {
  display: none;
}

.gallery-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.gallery-img-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-current-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: black;
}

.gallery-dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.65);
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
}

.gallery-dot {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0.70rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="gallery-wrapper">
          <div class="gallery-img-wrapper">
            <img src="https://belgium-guide.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/foto-hallerbosa-17.jpg" alt="" class="gallery-current-image">
            <div class="gallery-dots">
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gallery-all-images">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://belgium-guide.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/foto-hallerbosa-17.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://tumentoday.ru/media/gallery_images/bialowiezaforestctomaszwilk0.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/25978/ee1780c5-7223-4d25-8ed3-6c16c2c2a1fa/orig" alt="">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/25978/3b8dd671-b906-4216-a8f7-60b3ffdb5a16/orig" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Вариант посложнее, с таймаутами вместо таймера.

по клику удаляется старый таймаут и навешивается новый, таким образом отсчет идет непосредственно от момента клика

```js
$(".gallery-dot:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");

$(window).on("resize load", function() {
    $(".gallery-current-image").css("object-fit", 
      $(window).width() <= 767 ? "contain" : "cover");
})

var images = [];
var i = 0;

for (var image of $(".gallery-item-image")) {
  images.push($(image).attr("src"));
}

var to = setTimeout(tick, 2000);

$(".gallery-dot").on("click", function() {
  render(i = $(this).index());
  clearTimeout(to);
  to = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
});

function tick() {
  render(i = i === images.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1);
  to = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}

function render(index) {
  $(".gallery-current-image").attr("src", images[index]);
  $(".gallery-dot").css("background-color", "#a6a6a6")
         .eq(index).css("background-color", "#1a1a1a");
}
```

```css
.gallery-all-images,
.low-res {
  display: none;
}

.gallery-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.gallery-img-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery-current-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: black;
}

.gallery-dots {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.65);
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
}

.gallery-dot {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0.70rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="gallery-wrapper">
          <div class="gallery-img-wrapper">
            <img src="https://belgium-guide.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/foto-hallerbosa-17.jpg" alt="" class="gallery-current-image">
            <div class="gallery-dots">
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
              <div class="gallery-dot"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gallery-all-images">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://belgium-guide.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/foto-hallerbosa-17.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://tumentoday.ru/media/gallery_images/bialowiezaforestctomaszwilk0.jpg" alt="">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/25978/ee1780c5-7223-4d25-8ed3-6c16c2c2a1fa/orig" alt="">
            <img class="gallery-item-image" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/25978/3b8dd671-b906-4216-a8f7-60b3ffdb5a16/orig" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А в чём проблема была?

Comment: проблема была в том, что если кликнуть на точку хочется какое-то время наблюдать картинку, а код написан так, что с большой долей вероятности через меньше чем 2с произойдет переключение

Comment: @РустамГимранов это ошибка, я просто хотел убрать замыкание и проморгал второе обращение, спасибо

Comment: Мне очень нравится ваше 1 решение, спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, пояснить, почему после return'a интервал продолжает работать? Ведь он выходит из функции единовременно

Comment: @PythonNewbie я не понял про что Вы

Comment: @StrangerintheQ В 1 варианте ответа в начале интервала есть код который проверяет переменную  skipOneChange, и если она равна true, то return. Я читал в справочниках что return просто выходит из функции, но,как понял тут, для интервалов он просто пропускает один тик, правильно?

Comment: @PythonNewbie да, тело интервала, это функция и мы из нее выходим, а при следующем тике функция еще раз запускается

Comment: @StrangerintheQ понял. спасибо за фидбек :)

Comment: @PythonNewbie нет проблем, обращайтесь